# How to Click a popup Dialog Window

Tags: dialog, automation, window, applescript

I am having a problem with making a code to run DiskWarrior Automatically. The Problem is when i open the application, a SecurityAgent Dialog Pops up and asks for my username and password, and i do not know how to "click" into the Security Agent window so i can type in the username and password. I know how to code the name/password but i don't know how to "click" into the SercuirtyAgent window. I have tried using the UI inspector but thus far have had no luck. Does any one know how to code "clicking" the SecurityAgent window

Any/all help and feedback would be appreciated.

Here is what i have so far, still trying to figure it out:

```
tell application "DiskWarrior"
    open
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SecurityAgent"
        click text field 1
        delay 3
        keystroke "a user name"
                delay 3
                keystroke tab
                delay 3
                keystroke "a password"
                delay 3
                keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

You can focus it with `set frontmost to true` or `activate application "SecurityAgent"`.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SecurityAgent"
    set frontmost to true
end
```

You can also use UI scripting to set the value of the password field and click the OK button:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SecurityAgent"
    set value of text field 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window 1 to "password"
    click button 2 of group 2 of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Lauri.
I tried out those 2 suggestions but it didn't seem to do anything.
The code runs and opens diskwarrior but then just pauses when the security agent pops up.

Heres the code i have now
tell application "DiskWarrior"
 activate
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SecurityAgent"
 set value of text field 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window 1 to "password"
 click button 2 of group 2 of window 1
end tell
It still wont "focus" or "switch into" the popup window

Comment: Depending on what OSX version you have, the SecurityAgent dialog box has a different UI. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

For Yosemite, the SecurityAgent dialog box is different

```
tell application "DiskWarrior"
    open
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SecurityAgent"
        set value of text field 2 of window 1 to "yourPassword"
        click button 2 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```